# Get "cross product" of lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Can this be optimized

```
var groups = [];
for (var a in aList) {
  for (var bNumber in bList) {
    groups.push({ a: a, b: b });
  }
}
```

The code is actually fine, but I just realized that it looks like a cross product of two lists, so instead of looping `aList.length*bList.length` times, I wondered if there was some smart function to do this.

Comment: You can't solve this faster than O(n*m), this looks fine. (Don't forget about hasOwnProperty checks, if needed!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: [Don't use `for in` enumeration on arrays!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Julian [pointed out a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337733/get-cross-product-of-lists-in-javascript/66299622?noredirect=1#comment117220370_66299622) in my original answer where I was storing elements as opposed to indices.

---

The existing code is erroneous; there is no variable `b`.
I will assume `bNumber` was meant to be `b` (or the other way around; it doesn't matter).

Since you know that arrays are indexed `0...n` (I am assuming you declared the arrays in a way such that all indices in that range exist), you certainly shouldn't use a `for...in` loop (as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337733/get-cross-product-of-lists-in-javascript#comment50665739_31337733));
rather, you should explicitly code in the bounds in a standard `for` loop (or some nearly identical variant):

```js
var groups = [];

for (var a = 0; a < aList.length; a++){
  for (var b = 0; b < bList.length; b++){
    groups.push({a, b});
  }
}
```

You shouldn't generally be using `var` either;
you generally want to restrict the scope of your variables to directly within the block in which you are working, and you want to be able to make some variables unassignable.

```js
const groups = [];

for (let a = 0; a < aList.length; a++){
  for (let b = 0; b < bList.length; b++){
    groups.push({a, b});
  }
}
```

With those changes, this has runtime of around 11% of the code in the answer, with the error fixed.

## Original answer, assuming storing elements

First, since you know that you are dealing with lists, you should not use a `for...in` loop (as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337733/get-cross-product-of-lists-in-javascript#comment50665739_31337733)).
Next, this operation is generally called the *Cartesian product* or *direct product*, not the *cross product*.

The existing code is erroneous; there is no variable `b`.
I will assume `bNumber` was meant to be `b` (or the other way around; it doesn't matter).

The code can then be rewritten as

```js
var groups = aList.flatMap(a => bList.map(b => ({a, b})))
```

(Although you shouldn't generally be using `var` either!
You generally want to restrict the scope of your variables to directly within the block in which you are working.)

You will almost always find that the code in the question (with the error fixed) performs better, though, because `Array` maps have to handle some additional logic costs, like orchestrating the callbacks and list concatenation.
Switching your `for...in` loops to `for...of` loops actually halves the runtime in my tests.

Comment: If you think people shouldn't use `var`, then just don't use it in the first place and demonstrate with `const` or `let` instead. (As an aside, I disagree that it shouldn't be used, but that's a different discussion.)

Comment: By "doubles the performance", did you mean "doubles the running time" or "halves the running time"? (Otherwise a good answer, I'll upvote.)

Comment: Actually, I just noticed a mistake in your answer. The original code made pairs of *indices* into `aList` and `bList`. Your code makes pairs of *elements* of those arrays instead.

Comment: You're absolutely correct; I have updated the answer to reflect that.